# Loading properties from a custom config server using Eureka

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I want to bootstrap my web application with a set of properties that are supplied by a service that is registered with Eureka.

I set up Eureka, ConfigServer (REST service) & Client Application locally.

Eureka Server exposed in port `8761` has the service registered to it.
[image]

`/data` endpoint of the service responds with a set of key-value pairs as given below.
[image]

**Config Server Code**

```
@GetMapping("/data")
    public Map<String, String> getAllProperties(){
        
        Map<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
        dataMap.put("A", "1");
        dataMap.put("B", "2");
        dataMap.put("C", "3");
        dataMap.put("D", "4");
        dataMap.put("E", "5");
        dataMap.put("F", "6");
        dataMap.put("G", "7");
        
        return dataMap;
        
    }
```

**Client/Application Side**

Since I require customized handling of the response, I created a `CustomConfigLocator` class that implements `org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator` and override the `locate()` method to query and set the custom properties.

In order to query the data (properties) , I need an instance of `DiscoveryClient` to discover the `Config Server` and query the `/data` end point.

`CustomConfigLocator` is initialized while bootstrapping the application using `spring.factories` file.

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
com.config.client.ConfigClientApplication.CustomConfigLocator
```

The main class is annotated with **@EnableDiscoveryClient** and the bootstrap.properties are supplied with the following properties.

```
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled = true
spring.cloud.config.discovery.service-id = CUSTOMCONFIGSERVER
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Now coming to the real issue. As I mentioned earlier, an instance of `DiscoveryClient` is required to discover the Config Server instance from Eureka. But when I tried to inject (@Autowire) the instance of `org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient`, the application failed to start complaining that the instance of that type is not available in the container.

```
public class CustomConfigLocator implements PropertySourceLocator{
    
    @Autowired
    private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;
```

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'com.config.client.ConfigClientApplication.CustomConfigLocator':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'discoveryClient';
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:

Can anyone suggest a way to access the **DiscoveryClient** from the `CustomConfigLocator` class?

############## UPDATE-1 ################

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

Comment: It is quite surprising that no one has even put a comment even after declaring a bounty. Wondering if it is because the question is completely illogical or spring doesn't support this feature at all.. !!

Comment: could you add a list of dependencies of your project?

Comment: @Lokesh added dependencies

Comment: Hi, can you please provide all Eureka and Discovery related properties from your properties?

Comment: @VictorBjorn I have posted everything that I have in the bootstrap.properties. Please let me know if I am missing any.